# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I got error while coding NextJS 13 like this:
[image]

./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I using next-auth, tailwindcss and this is my next.config.js:
`/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig`

Anyone can help me fix it?